# SEVERE: WS00034: Two web services are being deployed with the same endpoint URL

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to redeploy in Netbeans with GlassFish.

```
SEVERE: WS00034: Two web services are being deployed with the same endpoint URL
```

I'm not using two web services with the same endpoint URL so I don't know where this exception is coming from.

UPDATE:
Also getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception while shutting down application container : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I'm only getting this error without any other errors or lines explaining why.

Comment: Clean your glassfish by undeploying all the applications and try to deploy yours.

Comment: Tried that, but still fails to deploy.

Comment: Then the problem might be in your application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You were right. I forgot to serialize my interceptor and it gave a vague NullPointerException that came from Weld or something. So now it works.

Comment: can you please answer your own question? I need an answer to this but you didnt put an answer up for your own quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearantly, I got a vague nullpointerexception from weld import because I forgot to serialize my interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was for me. Two method names were identical in two different classes.

In one class i had :

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "deleteRoute")
public void deleteRoute(@WebParam(name = "routeId") int routeId) {
}
```

and in the other i had :

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "deleteUser")
public void deleteRoute(@WebParam(name = "id") int id) {
}
```

I just renamed my second **deleteRoute** to **deleteUser** and it worked. But its kinda weird... i though WS would ignore the actual method, and only be interested in the operationName.

Comment: It should only be interested in the operationName, but you do know Netbeans & GlassFish. Netbeans & GlassFish do what they want. :P